# Unable to create/open lock file: \data\db\mongod.lock

Tags: windows, mongodb

I am follwing this tutorial: I am using 64-bit Windows 7 computer.
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/

I have installed MongoDB and starts the MongoDB file from the command prompt. Then I get the following error message:

Unable to create/open lock file: \data\db\mongod.lock

I don't know how to solve that problem.

Comment: Did you create that directory? `md \data\db`

Comment: whats the command line that you are entering?

Comment: It sounds like you had incorrect permissions for your `\data\db` directory, so `mongod.exe` was unable to create/open the lock file.

Comment: Gergo Erdosi: Yes that directory exist. alernerdev: I entered the command: C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>C:\"Program Files"\"MongoDB 2.6 Standard"\bin\mongod.exe - Stennie: How do I change the permission?

Answer (score 4):

Delete the mongod.lock file in the /data/db folder

Restart mongodb

Comment: The `mongod.lock` file is normally an indication of [unclean shutdown without journaling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/#indications) where database repair should be run. The lock file should not be deleted except as a last resort. In the context of this person's question, the error message is about the lock file either not existing or `mongod` not having permission to read it. If the lock file existed and was readable, the message would be "Unclean shutdown detected.".

Comment: I started the command prompt as an administrator and entered the folder in which mongod.lock is located. There I wrote the command: del mongod.lock      The response I get in the command prompt is that the file can't be reached because it is used in another process. I have no idea what process that is or how I end it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing a similar problem and i noted that some MongoDB processes were running in the background when i opened the task manager. so after i terminated the tasks and went to the mongod.lock file i was now able to delete it.